# Dragging local image in webpage crashes Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm working on a page where users can view/upload local files. Once the file has been selected, I'm displaying the image in the page. I've come across an issue that dragging such an image crashes my browser window (Chrome).

[Here's a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qCewu/)

Simple html:

`<input type='file'>`
`<img>`

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$('input').change(function(){
    var file = $('input').get(0).files;
    var fileReader=new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(e){
         $('img').attr('src',e.target.result);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
});
```

Poking around a bit more, it seems this is only a problem with large image files (such as uncompressed photos from an iPhone). This isn't necessarily a deal-breaker for the page but it is certainly annoying to accidentally drag an image and instantly crash the page.

Is there any good way to fix this?

Comment: got same problem, any hint?

Answer (score 3):

I solved using `Blob` :

```
   if (file !== undefined && window.FileReader !== undefined) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var self = this;

        reader.onload = function(e) {
           if (window.Blob) {
                var blob = new Blob([e.target.result]);
                window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                self.setSrc({"tempUrl" : blobURL}); //using backbone this refers to a model
           }
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    } else {
        if (!file)
            console.error("No file prevented");
        if (!window.FileReader)
            console.error("Your browser is not supported");
    }
```

As I could see, `readAsDataURL` kills the memory.